# select from session username

Tags: php, mysql, email, session

I've read all the questions or at least lots of them and what I see is lots of code that for a beginner like me doesn't help a lot...

Probably, you will say that I'm a noob to start making my own webpage with login, register, and all that stuff and I also see people talking about giving up on mysql stuff to avoid sql injection and all of those security details.

All I need to know is a simply a thing about 1 code I'm getting wrong.

```
$mail = mysql_query("select email from users where username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

This is the variavel I have made to get the email of the actual user in the logged in session.

When I put your email is `<?php echo"$mail".; ?>`, it gives me the next detail:

> your email is Resource id #8.

Why am I getting that?  I've made the variable in a place with session started but I don't get what I have in that column on the specified user.

Sorry if I shouldn't post that in here, but I really don't see anyone with the same problem.  All I see is complex codes and I really don't understand a lot of that.

I'm still a beginner, so if you guys can give me an hand, I will be grateful.

Comment: `mysql_query()` returns a resource, no data. http://nz1.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: 1 more thing i have lots of scripts with login register and all the site made already but im doing my own to start learning how it works or not, so thats why im asking that cause lots of the scripts have something like $_POST['username'] and im using session username not POST dont really know the diference between them :s

Comment: Nobody is going to call you a "noob" for making your site.  Nobody has ever said "don't use a database as it might get hacked".  What you need to do is use a database properly with prepared/parameterized queries so you don't have to worry about SQL injection issues.  Since you're just learning, I highly recommend **not** using `mysql_query()`.  Just stop now... it isn't the right way to use a database.  I recommend PDO as it provides a nice object-oriented approach to using multiple databases.  There are alternatives.

Comment: Why are you querying email of loggedin user again ? You can store the email also in session in the first place.

Comment: Sarfraz how you do that? you need the comand i typed in there right? i have that comand in the config php file thats what you are talking about right?

Comment: @Brad, im loking at tutorials on an hold book and on internet, for me i think is easier to learn the most used first, and the most simple, and then go to the actual code, cause when i open stuff talking about mysqli it looks even worst then mysql lol, is like chinese for me :s
but if you can point me to the right tutorials i will thank you, like msqli for beginners

Comment: @kjonh2 If you're reading a tutorial that tells you to use `mysql_query()`, stop and get a different tutorial.  `mysql_query()` is **not** the most used these days, and nor should it be.  I've taught a lot of folks how to get started with PHP, and when it comes to databases, most people understand PDO more easily than they did when I was teaching `mysql_*`.  If you know how to program in other languages, this tutorial might be a good place to start:  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use mysql_fetch_[array|object|assoc] PHP function

```
$res = mysql_query("select email from users where username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$field = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $field['email'];
```

Comment: thks i knew it was something with the fetch function for all i ve seing but didnt knew how to do it ;) thank you thats what im looking for ;)

Comment: This is **wide open** to SQL injection problems, and should not be used.  **Always** escape arbitrary data used in queries.  Best answer would be to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2):

You have to fetch the returning rows of your query:
`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query/$mail);`

All the columns you queried will be in the array `$row` now.

`print "Email: " . $row['email'];`

This example assumes the query only returned one row.
If you were to query for several rows, you have to call `mysql_fetch_assoc` each time you wanted a new row:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Take what you need.

```
$user = strip_tags($_SESSION['username']);

$sql = sprintf("SELECT FROM email WHERE username='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($user));

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$mail = $row['email'];


echo "Your email is" .$mail;
```

The strip_tags() method will remove any HTML tags in the submitted entry.

I like to use the sprintf() method when making single row queries because it's a lot faster to just paste and change attribute names then worry about using the correct quote syntax.

Once your query is process you need to fetch the results then you can access the data inside the tables.

I hope this helps you out.